# Does Albert Einsteen Really Read Bhagavad Gita?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, ramayana, bhagavad-gita

I have heard that Bhagavad Gita helps Albert Einsteen to discover E=mc^2 .
Is that true ?
Does Bhagavad Gita helps him to become success in his life ?

Comment: Whether Einstein read the Bhagavad Gita isn't really a question about Hinduism, so I'm closing your question.  By the way, I don't think Einstein read the Gita, but Oppenheimer, the physicist who worked on the atomic bomb did.  After the first atomic bomb test he was reminded of the Gita verse "Now I am become death, the destroyer of worlds."

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan I think OP is asking whether the formula E=mc^2 discovered by Einstein has anything to do with Bhagavad gita.  but not whether Einstein read bhagavad gita...

Comment: @Mr_Green The question seemed more about asking "How did the Bhagavad Gita influence Einstein?"  Anyway, asking whether the Bhagavad Gita talks about the concept of E=mc^2 would be way too speculative for the site.

Comment: Einstein had mystical and spiritual thoughts, which many have construed as non-dualistic. But have never heard that he did so at a young age or that he read the Gita. A good source would be two of his writings: "The World As I See It" (1949) and "Ideas and Opinions" (1954).